# Radius of convergence of $\,x^2\big(1+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n}{(2n)!}2^{2n-1}x^{2n}\big)$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, convergence-divergence, power-series

I want to calculate the radius of convergence for

$$x^2(1+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n}{(2n)!}2^{2n-1}x^{2n})$$

We defined the radius of convergence as
$R:=\frac{1}{\lim \sup_{n \to\infty}\sqrt[k](|a_n|)}$ for $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_nz^n$

But how can I bring my power series into the form $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_nz^n$ or how else can I prove that it converges everywhere?

It's the power series of $x^2\cos(x)^2$ if that helps.

Thanks!

Comment: Set $y=2x$.  You should see immediately that the radius of convergence in $y$ is $\infty$.  So, it's $\infty$ for $x$ too.

Answer (score 1):

Set $w=x^2$, then the power series becomes
$$
w\left(1+\frac{1}{2}\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n2^{2n}w^n}{(2n)!}\right) \tag{1}
$$
with coefficents
$$
a_n=\frac{(-1)^n2^{2n}}{(2n)!}
$$
and
$$
\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}=-\frac{4}{(2n+1)(2n+2)},
$$
and hence $\,\big|\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}\big|\to 0$, which implies that  $(1)$ has infinite radius of convergence, and hence converges for every $w\in\mathbb R$ (even in $\mathbb C$). Therefore, the original power series also converges for every $w\in\mathbb R$ (even in $\mathbb C$), and thus its radius of convergence is infinite.